# Django - Unable to lookup 'u'

Tags: python, django, django-models

yesterday everything was working perfect, today i enter to the admin and this error is showing when i click in "usuarios_aux" model...

`Unable to lookup 'u' on Usuario_aux or Usuario_AuxAdmin`

Why is this happening? heres the traceback.

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://provisional.jetint.webfactional.com/admin/clients/usuario_aux/
>
> Django Version: 1.7.3 Python Version: 2.7.9 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig', 
>   'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'adminplus',  'clients',  'currier')
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Template error: In template
>   /home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91    Unable to lookup 'u' on Usuario_aux or
>   Usuario_AuxAdmin    81 :         {% endif %}
>
> 82 :       {% endblock %}
>
> 83 :
>
> 84 :       {% csrf_token %}
>
> 85 :       {% if cl.formset %}
>
> 86 :         {{ cl.formset.management_form }}
>
> 87 :       {% endif %}
>
> 88 :
>
> 89 :       {% block result_list %}
>
> 90 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and
>   cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
>
> 91 :            {% result_list cl %}
>
> 92 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and
>   cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
>
> 93 :       {% endblock %}
>
> 94 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
>
> 95 :
>
> 96 :
>
> 97 :
>
> 98 : {% endblock %}
>
> 99 :
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     137.                 response = response.render() File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py"
>   in render
>     103.             self.content = self.rendered_content File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     80.         content = template.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     148.             return self._render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     142.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     80.             return node.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     126.         return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     142.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     80.             return node.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     126.         return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     142.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     80.             return node.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     80.             return node.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     80.             return node.render(context) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     1207.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py"
>   in result_list
>     307.     headers = list(result_headers(cl)) File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py"
>   in result_headers
>     101.             return_attr=True File "/home/jetint/webapps/jet_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/utils.py"
>   in label_for_field
>     324.                 raise AttributeError(message)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/clients/usuario_aux/
>   Exception Value: Unable to lookup 'u' on Usuario_aux or
>   Usuario_AuxAdmin

how i can fix this?

model:

```
class Usuario_aux(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    clave = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    correo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

admin.py:

```
class Usuario_AuxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'correo')
    search_fields = ('user', 'correo')
admin.site.register(Usuario_aux, Usuario_AuxAdmin)
```

Comment: you need to at least post your models for the form and the class ... apparently its trying to render the u attribute ... which is not in the class ...

Comment: There's no 'u' attr... check the model

Comment: are you using a AdminFormClass for it?  ... something is trying to access `Usuario_aux.u`

Comment: just posted the admin.py part of it... but its weird... yesterday was working perfectly

Comment: you could just try adding `u="uuuuuuuu"` or something to the class and see where you see all those u's ... is there a relationship that might be looking for `usario.u`  or something? (maybe it was user and someone accidentaly deleted ser?

Comment: Are you *sure* that is exactly what you have for `list_display` on that model? You would get that error if, for example, you had just `'user'` or even `('user')` without the comma, because Python will treat that as a single string and try to iterate through it.